# How do I split and Array into two parts based on type- Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to split an array into 2 types based on type: Buyer or Supplier. If you look at the last snippet, there is an array called newCompanies where there are company names with the type of company.

I am trying to get that company array data from local storage and I want to split them into 2 arrays so that I can have 2 types of listboxes. One is the Buyer listbpx and the other is supplier listbox.

Thanks in advance

```js
var companies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newCompany"));

var splitted = companies.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  if (obj[item.type] == null) {
    obj[item.type] = [];
  }
  obj[item.type].push(item);
  return obj;
}, {});

splitted.buyer;
splitted.supplier;
$scope.companies.push(splitted.supplier);

$scope.companies.push(splitted.buyer);
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Company</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addForm.addCompany.$invalid && !addForm.addCompany.$pristine }">
    <select class="form-control" name="addCompany"
            placeholder="Select Company"
            ng-options="company for company in companies"
            ng-model="newUser.company" ng-required="true">
    </select>
    <span class="help-block" ng-show="addForm.addCompany.$invalid && !addForm.addCompany.$pristine">
Your Company is required.
   </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var newCompany = [{
    name: "Huawei", // -->COMPANY NAME
    email: "Drath@yahoo.com",
    phone: "123-123-1234",
    owner: "Drath",
    type: "buyer"
  },
  {
    name: "Asus", // -->COMPANY NAME
    email: "Vadar@yahoo.com",
    phone: "999-123-8888",
    owner: "Vadar",
    type: "supplier"
  },
  {
    name: "Acer", // -->COMPANY NAME
    email: "Radal@yahoo.com",
    phone: "676-989-8888",
    owner: "Randall",
    type: "supplier"
  }
];
window.localStorage.setItem("newCompany", JSON.stringify(newCompany));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var newCompany = [{
    name: "Huawei", // -->COMPANY NAME
    email: "Drath@yahoo.com",
    phone: "123-123-1234",
    owner: "Drath",
    type: "buyer"
  },
  {
    name: "Asus", // -->COMPANY NAME
    email: "Vadar@yahoo.com",
    phone: "999-123-8888",
    owner: "Vadar",
    type: "supplier"
  },
  {
    name: "Acer", // -->COMPANY NAME
    email: "Radal@yahoo.com",
    phone: "676-989-8888",
    owner: "Randall",
    type: "supplier"
  }
];

let buyers = [], suppliers = [];
for (let company of newCompany) {
  if (company.type === "buyer")
    buyers.push(company);
  else
    suppliers.push(company);
}

console.log("Buyers:");
console.log(buyers);
console.log("Suppliers:");
console.log(suppliers);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It totally works! Can you please tell me how this" let company of newCompany" works?

Comment: It's a foreach loop for iterables (like arrays, maps, strings, etc.), you can learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 0):

With a reduce:

```
var companies = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('newCompany'));

var splitted = companies.reduce(function (obj, item) {
  if (obj[item.type] == null) { obj[item.type] = []; }
  obj[item.type].push(item);
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Will result in `splitted` looking like this:

```
{
  buyer: [{name: "Huawei", ... }],
  supplier: [{name: "Asus", ... }, {name: "Acer", ... }]
}
```

And then grab the information from `splitted`:

```
splitted.buyer;    // -> [{name: "Huawei", ... }]
splitted.supplier; // -> [{name: "Asus", ... }, {name: "Acer", ... }]
```

This has the additional benefit, that if you add a third "type" of company later, you won't have to change a single line of code.

Comment: I tried it. Its not working. I am getting [object, object] in the listbox. I have updated the code in my question please check that.

Comment: The fact that you see `[object Object]` in the `<select>` elements has nothing to do with the way the array is divided, but it has to do with how Angular constructs the final HTML from the array contents. I'm not much of an expert on Angular to be honest, but by looking at the code you provided I'd suggest looking into `ng-options` and `ng-model`

Comment: @Vaibhav27  According to the AngularJS docs, you have to change `ng-options` to something like this: `company.name for company in companies` to display the name part: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions